# How to create a bridge-header file for C++ or .mm (Objective-C++) file as we do for .m and .h?

Tags: swift2, ios9, objective-c++, xcode7.2, bridging-header

I saw in a github(https://github.com/sandym/swiftpp) project on using "cxx-Bridging-Header.h" header file for .cpp(C++) and .mm (objective-C++) file and learnt that it was build by "Run Script" but didn't got any clear idea about how to create the header. Please help on how to create such a header?

Answer (score 0):

Go to, File -> new File -> iOS source -> header file .h -> click on project to bring up build settings, look for Objective-C Bridging Header double click in blank field to bring up blank view -> drag and drop your newly created .h file into blank view till the file path is there (it might disappear on you a couple of times) -> go to .h file and #import "cxx-Bridging-Header.h" build and you should be good to go.

Good luck!